# Connecting to Oracle Database in Haskell using HDBC

Tags: oracle, haskell, odbc

I was trying to work with Oracle Database from Haskell and have faced with such problem.
So, there is this code.

    module Main where

```hs
import Database.HDBC
import Database.HDBC.ODBC

main :: IO ()

main = do
        let connectionString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=valera;Pwd=2562525;"
        let ioconn = connectODBC connectionString
        conn <- ioconn
        vals <- quickQuery conn "SELECT * FROM PERSONS_TEST" []
        print vals
        return ()
```

Pretty simple, huh? But that won't work. With this connection string the error is

```hs
*** Exception: SqlError {seState = "[\"HY090\"]", seNativeError = -1, seErrorMsg = "sqlGetInfo SQL_TXN_CAPABLE: [\"0: [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle]\\65533...
```

and then 65333 repeats many times. And with this

```hs
Provider=msdaora;Data Source=127.0.0.1;User Id=valera;Password=2562525;
```

the error is

```hs
*** Exception: SqlError {seState = "[\"IM002\"]", seNativeError = -1, seErrorMsg = "connectODBC/sqlDriverConnect: [\"0: [Microsoft][\\65533...
```

and 65333 repeats again till the end
I suppose, that the problem is in connection string, but I had tried a whole bunch of them (I've used http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

I'm using Haskell Platform 2011.4.0.0, GHC 7.0.4, Oracle Database XE 11.2 on Windows 7 64-bit. Microsoft MDAC SDK installed.

Comment: Did you create an odbc connection using Odbc tool in Administrative Tools?

Comment: Oh, I didn't. Maybe I don't fully understand the concept of ODBC. I will try.

Answer (score 2):

\65533 and so on is the symbols of ODBC driver error message string in your locale (RU?).  I find the best way so on to develop in english locale system, thus error messages in ghci console shown in english language and can be read.